# Threepart table footnotes with brackets

Tags: brackets, threeparttable

Currently the threeparttable displays the footnotes and references to footnotes as showed in following picture.
[image]

How can I configure treeparttable to display the reference to the footnote with [a], [b] and [c] and list it under the footnote section with "[a] Note one", "[b] Note one" and so on?

PS: I would like to keep the references in the table and the footnote section superscript (but I do not know how to write superscript with StackExchange syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(rewrote the answer to focus on modifying the `\tnote` macro)

Quoting from page 1 of the user guide of the [threeparttable](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/threeparttable/) package:

> There is nothing automatic about the notes.

For your use case, though, obtaining the desired formatting, *viz.*, surrounding the arguments of `\tnote` to be surrounded by square brackets automatically, is actually not too difficult, since it "only" requires hacking the `\tnote` macro itself. The package's definition of `\tnote` is as follows:

```
\def\tnote#1{\protect\TPToverlap{\textsuperscript{\TPTtagStyle{#1}}}}
```

To obtain your desired format, overwrite it via

```
\def\tnote#1{\protect\TPToverlap{\textsuperscript{[\TPTtagStyle{#1}]}}}
```

Can you spot the difference?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[para,flushleft]{threeparttable}
\def\tnote#1{\protect\TPToverlap{\textsuperscript{[\TPTtagStyle{#1}]}}}

\usepackage{booktabs,array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\sffamily % optional
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Solvent screening}
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{3}{w{l}{1in}} @{}}
   \toprule
   entry\tnote{a} & ee\tnote{b} & conv.\tnote{c} \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\smallskip
\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
   \item[a] Note one   \item[b] Note two   \item[c] Note three
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```