# Threeparttable align footnotes containing brackets

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lyx, footnotes, threeparttable

I use `threeparttable` to format my tables. I also use brackets for footnote references. As you can see in the following picture, the 2nd line of footnote `[a]` is not aligned. The line starting with `0.0` is starting to far left.

[image]

How can I correct this?

Best regards,
wewa00

PS: Here is the sample LaTeX code to reproduce this issue.

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 2.3.6 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
% --------- change figure and table caption size -----------
\usepackage{caption} % to change font size of image caption
\captionsetup[figure]{font=footnotesize,labelfont=footnotesize} % available values are scriptsize, footnotesize, small, normalsize, large, and Large.
\captionsetup[table]{font=footnotesize,labelfont=footnotesize} % available values are scriptsize, footnotesize, small, normalsize, large, and Large.
% -----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs} % booktabs: to support centering of table
\usepackage{etoolbox} % to support footnotesize within table
\appto\TPTnoteSettings{\footnotesize} % footnote font size within table
\def\tnote#1{\protect\TPToverlap{\textsuperscript{[\TPTtagStyle{#1}]}}} % brackets in table footnotes

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{}

\centering
\begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{>{\centering}m{1.2cm}>{\centering}m{4cm}>{\centering}m{3cm}>{\centering}m{1.8cm}>{\centering}m{1.9cm}}
\hline 
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5\tabularnewline[\doublerulesep]
\hline 
\noalign{\vskip\doublerulesep}
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] Loremips umdolor sit ahmet 0.00 lore mipsum, 00 lor\% ipsumlor emi 0.00 lore ipsumlor ip 0.0 lo remipsu mlo 00 l lo remi psumloremip.
\item [b] Loremipsum lor emipsu LORE.
\item [c] Loremipsum dol ORE.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want the first word of the second line to align with "[a]"  or with "Loremips"?

Comment: For the former, use `flushleft` (either globally as a package option of locally as an option for the `tablenotes` environment. For the latter, you could try `\def\TPTnoteSettings{\setlength\labelwidth{1em}}`.

Comment: @leandriis I would like to align the 2nd line with "Loremips"

Comment: @leandriis `\def\TPTnoteSettings{\setlength\labelwidth{1em}}` is working as desired. Could you please write an answer?

Comment: Running `\def\TPTnoteSettings{\setlength\labelwidth{1em}}` does a lot more to the appearance of the table notes than just affect the indentation amount. Unless you want to clobber the default properties of `\TPTnoteSettings`, you really ought to run `\apptocmd{\TPTnoteSettings}{\setlength\labelwidth{1em}}{}{}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution achieves your formatting objective. Observe that it's not a good idea to execute `\def\TPTnoteSettings{\setlength\labelwidth{1em}}`, as doing so clobbers the default setting of the macro. That's why the code below contains the instruction

```
\apptocmd{\TPTnoteSettings}{\setlength\labelwidth{1em}}{}{}
```

[image]

In the code below, I've also cleaned up and simplified your preamble code. By the way, the `booktabs` package is utterly unrelated to "support centering of table". Instead, it provides macros -- such as `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` -- to draw well-spaced horizontal lines. Note also that the `\begin{threeparttable}` instruction should come before, not after, the `\caption` statement.

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % "latin9" -- are you serious ?!
\usepackage[verbose,vmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=3cm,rmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}

\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\providecommand\tabularnewline{\\} % just in case it isn't already defined

\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{skip=0.333\baselineskip,
              font=footnotesize % really?
             }
             
\usepackage{booktabs} % booktabs: to support centering of table
    %% No!! 'booktabs' is utterly unrelated to centering a table.
    %% Who on earth gave you this erroneous piece of information?
    
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for '\AtBeginEnvironment' macro and '\apptocmd' macro
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tablenotes}{\footnotesize\smallskip} 
\def\tnote#1{\protect\TPToverlap{\textsuperscript{[\TPTtagStyle{#1}]}}} % cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/578489
\apptocmd{\TPTnoteSettings}{\setlength\labelwidth{1em}}{}{} % <-- new


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{threeparttable} % <-- should come _before_ '\caption'
\caption{}

\begin{tabular}{@{} M{1.2cm} M{4cm} M{3cm} M{1.8cm} M{1.9cm} @{}}
\toprule
1\tnote{a} & 2\tnote{b} & 3 & 4 & 5\tnote{c} \tabularnewline 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a] Loremips umdolor sit ahmet 0.00 lore mipsum, 00 lor\% ipsumlor emi
         0.00 lore ipsumlor ip Lo lo remipsu mlo 00 l lo remi psumloremip.
\item[b] Loremipsum lor emipsu LORE.
\item[c] Loremipsum dol ORE.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I can not really recall where `booktabs` was advised. I removed it now, and everything works as before so far. Regarding `\begin{threeparttable}` and `\caption`: Putting `\begin{threeparttable}` before `\caption` does not work for me. This scrambles my formatting. I display an image between the table caption and the table itself. To show you this I would need some time to prepare the sample.

Comment: @wewa - The `threeparttable` environment has three formal components (hence its name) :a `\caption` statement, a `tabular`-like environment, and a `tablenotes` environment. By not including the `\caption` statement *inside* the `threeparttable` environment, you're not using the package's machinery appropriately. It's not clear what you mean by "scrambles the formatting"; did you maybe fail to place the `\centering` *before* the `\begin{threeparttable}` directive? (Observe that in my answer, `\centering` comes before `\begin{threeparttable}` which, in turn, comes before `\caption`.)

Comment: Here you can see how I use it currently: https://gist.github.com/wewa00/a657bc6dadbcda51f6e68e4c1fff0246. If `\begin{threeparttable}` comes before `\caption`, the image and caption are not aligned centered.

Comment: I misused the answer feature of StackExchange to illustrate the issue I have here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/580788/231568